# Multiplication in assembly 8086 wrong result

Tags: assembly, masm, x86-16, masm32, tasm

I am trying to make a multiplication using the register AX. I have ax=1000 (3E8h), and I want to multiply it by 10. I get this result in ax, after the mul command is executed: 910h, which is 2320 (base 10). I should get 2710h which is 10000 (base 10).

Here is my code:

```
assume cs:code, ds:data
data segment
    zece db 10
data ends
code segment
start:
    mov ax, data
    mov ds, ax
    mov dx, 0
    mov ax, 3E8h
    mul zece
    mov ax, 4C00h
    int 21h
code ends
end start
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

The instruction [mul](http://x86.renejeschke.de/html/file_module_x86_id_210.html) has several variants. When you multiply with a 8-bit memory object the result is `AL*[mem/8]`. In your case you multiply

```
0xE8 * 0xA = 0x910  or
232 * 10 = 2320
```

Change the data definition to get the desired result:

```
data segment
    zece dw 10
data ends
```

Comment: Also note that you do not need to clear DX before doing the multiplication.